# xstream handles non-english character

Tags: java

I have the following code :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package helloworld;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author yccheok
 */
public class Test {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <A> A fromXML(Class c, File file) {
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
            Object object = xStream.fromXML(inputStream);
            if (c.isInstance(object)) {
                return (A)object;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                    inputStream = null;
                }
                catch (java.io.IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <A> A fromXML(Class c, String filePath) {
        return (A)fromXML(c, new File(filePath));
    }

    public static boolean toXML(Object object, File file) {
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            xStream.toXML(object, outputStream);
        }
        catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                    outputStream = null;
                }
                catch (java.io.IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean toXML(Object object, String filePath) {
        return toXML(object, new File(filePath));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "\u6210\u4EA4\u91CF";
        // print ???
        System.out.println(s);
        // fine! show 成交量
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
        toXML(s, "C:\\A.XML");
        String o = fromXML(String.class, "C:\\A.XML");
        // show ???
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, o);
    }
}
```

I run the following code through command prompt in Windows Vista.

1) May I know why System.out.println unable to print out Chinese Character in console?

2) I open up the xstream file. The saved value is

```
<string>???</string>
```

How can I make xstream save Chinese Character correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [XStream FAQ](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#XML), it generates output (1) with whatever your platform default encoding is, and (2) without an XML prologue. Which is a really bad combination.

The FAQ recomments using `toXml(Writer)`. If you use an `OutputStreamWriter`, you can specify the encoding during construction. Since XStream doesn't emit a prologue, I recommend using "UTF-8", as that's what the XML spec requires.

Alternatively, I suppose you could follow one of the other recommendations in the FAQ, and manually write an XML prologue into the stream with your default encoding. I don't recommend that.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use "UTF-16" encoding? Isn't Java String store data in UTF-16?

Comment: You can use UTF-16. And for Chinese text, a UTF-16 file should be smaller than a UTF-8 file. However, if you go that route, you need to emit a BOM at the start of the file, and I don't believe that `OutputStreamWriter` does that automatically. See http://www.xml.com/axml/testaxml.htm for more information about encodings.

Answer (score 1):

If the default character encoding on the platform isn't capable of displaying Chinese, you need to override it in the console *and* when launching Java. To set Java's character encoding, set the `file.encoding` property *on the command-line* (it won't work if you call `System.setProperty()` in your program).

```
java -Dfile.encoding=Big5 ...
```

I don't know the command for setting the console encoding in Vista. In Windows XP, it was the `chcp` ("change code page") command.